# what is the need of GET method in PHP,JAVA ot Dot NET, when you have many advantages of POST over GET method?

Tags: html

In all languages there are GET and POST methods for transfering data. POST is more secure then GET and data transfer size limits are also there. So why in all languages there is a GET method? What are the advantages of the GET method?

Comment: POST isn't any more secure than GET

Answer (score 2):

GET data is stored in URL, so page with GET request can be bookmarked or linked. You just can't do that with POST. Almost every web-page uses GET to specify requested page, even stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Note that GET, POST (and PUT, DELETE, etc.) are not methods of the language you program in, but are HTTP protocol methods.

What do you mean by "transfer data"?

If, by this, you mean to collect data from the user in the browser (or other client application) and then send to the server for updating a database or to process in some other way that creates/updates a resource on the server, consider the POST or PUT method instead (depending on whether the action is idempotent or not).

If, however, you mean to collect data from the user and send to the server to retrieve information and, without updating/creating a resource on the server, the GET method would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful for direct linking for the user. You can immediately put the thread number in the address bar in forums or video numbers for videos in YouTube instead of having to browse the entire site.